# Android Increase touch target of edit text as per accessibility without affecting design

Tags: android, android-edittext, accessibility

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/caregiverFirstName"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/shape_round_corner_edit_text"
  android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_regular"
  android:hint="@string/type_here"
  android:imeOptions="actionDone"
  android:inputType="text"
  android:maxLength="50"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:paddingStart="16dp"
  android:paddingTop="12dp"
  android:paddingEnd="16dp"
  android:paddingBottom="12dp"
  android:textColor="@color/main_vital_text_color"
  android:textColorHint="@color/edit_hint_color"
  android:textSize="16sp" />
```

If I add 14dp padding to top and bottom then the editText is as per accessibility but it is affecting design and increasing height of editText which I don't want. Is there any alternate solution to increase touch target with affecting design?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding padding, consider using

```
android:minHeight="48dp" android:minWidth="48dp"
```